# Less :hover not overwriting :before color

Tags: html, hover, less

I have a link with a :before pseudo class.

I'm trying to style it so that the content is grey, but red on hover, using LESS. However, I can't find any combination of code where both the default color and the hover color work.

Code Pen:
http://codepen.io/niahc/pen/zvNaPj

LESS code:

```
.icon-support:before {
  content: "acvzssd";
}

.help {
  .icon-support {
    &:before {
      color: grey;
    }
    &:hover,
    &:focus,
    &:active {
      color: red !important;
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<a class="help" href="#">
  <span class="icon-support"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: Side note: use double colons (`::`) for pseudo elements and single (`:`) for states (like `:hover` etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this to work, you just need to specify the style on the `::before` pseudoelement instead of on the element itself, so your final LESS code would look like this:

```
.icon-support::before {
  content: "acvzssd";
}

.help {
  .icon-support {
    &::before {
      color: grey;
    }
    &:hover::before, /*   <-- Change to "before" here */
    &:focus::before, /*   <-- and here */
    &:active::before { /* <-- and here */
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

Fixed Codepen: http://codepen.io/maxlaumeister/pen/xwgzJQ

---

And here is a **Live Demo** using the compiled CSS:

```css
.icon-support::before {
  content: "acvzssd";
}
.help .icon-support::before {
  color: grey;
}
.help .icon-support:hover::before,
.help .icon-support:focus::before,
.help .icon-support:active::before {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a class="help" href="#">
  <span class="icon-support"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: Interesting, I had tried nesting the hover classes inside the before class, but not vice-versa. Never thought the order of the pseudo-classes would matter

Answer (score 3):

i dont know less, but that worked :D

```
.icon-support:before {
  content: "acvzssd";
}

.help {
  .icon-support {
    &:before {
      color: grey;
    }
    &:hover,
    &:focus,
    &:active {
      &:before {
        color: red;
      }
    }
  }
}
```